# Application of sed command several times on a file

Tags: bash, file, sed, process, command

I want to apply several times this sed command to a file:

```
sed '1~2d' file.txt>file1.txt
```

let's say I want to do it 4 times, is there a way to do this process getting also the intermediate files?

Thank you in advance

Best Regards

(The files are 1m UTM coordinates and I want to reduce the accuracy of the measurement to make the files manageable)

Comment: You want to keep every Nth line for some value of N?

Comment: To only keep every 16th line, you can use `awk 'NR%16 == 0' file.txt` directly.

Comment: a) you're using the wrong tool and b) show some sample input and expected output so we can help you do it the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It SOUNDS like what you need is (replace `6` and `2` with whatever numbers you want):

```
awk '{for (i=2;i<=6;i+=2) if (!(NR%i)) print > ("file"i)}' file
```

e.g. run in an empty directory:

```
$ seq 1 20 | awk '{for (i=2;i<=6;i+=2) if (!(NR%i)) print > ("file"i)}'

$ lf
file2  file4  file6

$ cat file2
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20

$ cat file4
4
8
12
16
20

$ cat file6
6
12
18
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mv file.txt file0.txt
for i in `seq 1 10`; do
    sed '1~2d' file$(($i-1)).txt > file$i.txt
done
mv file0.txt file.txt
```

It will make 10 files named file1.txt, file2.txt etc. Each of these files have the sed command run on the previous file.

BTW, the `$(())` is bash arithmetic evaluation. That is how the subtraction with 1 is done.

Comment: This looks like what I want to do, but for some reason while executing the .sh I'm not getting the different files. Thank you very much anyways

Comment: This works perfectly fine on my end. What you probably want to do is replace all occurences of `file.txt` in the above code with whatever your filename is.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this the opposite way around:

```
sed -n -i '16~16p' file.txt
```

The `-n` option suppresses `sed`'s default behavior of printing the buffer after processing each line.  The `'p'` command prints the ones you want.

The `-i` option tells `sed` to process the named file "in-place", which really means it will manage creating a temp file and, on success, replacing the original with it.  This is a lot safer than redirecting output straight to the file that `sed` is reading as input.